# Java Mail API - Datasource from FileInputStream

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, javax.activation

Am integrating JavaMailAPI in my webapplication. I have to embed images in the html body. How do i get the images from the src/main/resource directory instead of hard code the image path.

Please find the below code that i have hard coded the image path.

```
try {
messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
DataSource fds = new FileDataSource("C:\\email\\logo_email.png");
messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID","<image>");
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
message.setContent(multipart);
Transport.send(message);
System.out.println("Done");
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I want to get the images from the following code : ( src/main/resource )

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
FileInputStream fileinputstream = new FileInputStream(new 
File(classLoader.getResource("email/logo_email.png").getFile()));
```

I dont have idea to call fileinputstream inside DataSource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `URL.getFile()` as it returns the filename part of the `URL`...

Use `URLDataSource` instead of `FileDataSource`. Try something like this:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
URL url = classLoader.getResource("email/logo_email.png");
DataSource ds = new URLDataSource(url);
```

### Edit

In Web applications `getClass().getClassLoader()` might not get the correct class loader. Should use the `Thread`'s context class loader...

Comment: Now am getting below error.    java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javax.activation.URLDataSource.getContentType(URLDataSource.java:78)

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javax.activation.URLDataSource.getContentType(URLDataSource.java:78)
 at javax.activation.DataHandler.getContentType(DataHandler.java:205)